# How do I navigate(redirect) to any page I want in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

Hi guys can you please help me with my problem I'm new to Angular, So I tried every possible solution I even delete and reinstall the node_module, exit and enter the terminal type again `ng serve` and `this.router.navigateByUrl('/user');` or  `this.router.navigate(['/works']);`  it won't redirect to my desired page and instead it redirects to my home page.

My main problem in work-details.component.html:

```
<a href="" (click)="goBack()">Go Back</a>
```

My main problem in work-details.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router} from '@angular/router';

@Component({ 
      selector: 'app-work-details',
      templateUrl: './work-details.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./work-details.component.css']
})

export class WorkDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) { }

    ngOnInit() {}

    goBack () {
        this.router.navigate(['/works']);
    }

};
```

I have another code the same with work-details.component.ts but I don't think the two ts component would not conflict as long as the attributes or the elements are unique(correct me if I'm wrong). Anyway ill provide you my other ts component:

My other ts component abt-details.component.html:

```
<a href="" (click)="sendMeHome()">Go Back to Home</a>
```

My other ts component abt-details.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';   
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({ 
      selector: 'app-abt-details',
      templateUrl: './abt-details.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./abt-details.component.css']
})

export class AbtDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.route.params.subscribe(res => console.log(res.id));
    }

    sendMeHome() {
      this.router.navigate(['/about']);
    }

};
```

I hope gave you enough information to my problem and apologies if type the wrong line of code of this post just let me know guys.

Sorry I didn't put the router module thank you everyone for reminding me, my apologies.

I've included all my components in my `app-routing.module.ts` apologies again if it is a lot more confusing I just wanna make my page to redirect to a page I want. Just please focus on the `WorksComponent` I know theirs something wrong the way I route the components. If you find any flaws in my routing just let me know.

My app-routing.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';
import { AbtDetailsComponent } from './abt-details/abt-details.component';
import { DetailsComponent } from './details/details.component';
import { WorksComponent } from './works/works.component';
import { WorkDetailsComponent } from './works/work-details/work-details.component';
import { WorkDescriptionComponent } from './works/work-details/work-description/work-description.component';

const routes: Routes = [

    {
       path: '',
       component: HomeComponent
    },  
    {
       path: 'about', 
       component: AboutComponent
    },  
    {
       path: 'about/:id', 
       component: DetailsComponent
    },
    {
       path: 'about/details/:id', 
       component: AbtDetailsComponent
    },
    {
       path: 'works', 
       component: WorksComponent
    },
    {
       path: 'works/:id', 
       component: WorkDetailsComponent
    },
    {
       path: 'works/details/:id', 
       component: WorkDescriptionComponent
    }

];

@NgModule({
    imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
    exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

I also included the `app.module.ts` file I just in case you want to see it also.

My app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { routes } from './app.router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';
import { AbtSec01Component } from './about/abt-sec01/abt-sec01.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './navbar/navbar.component';
import { ErrorComponent } from './error/error.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './footer/footer.component';
import { MainComponent } from './main/main.component';
import { HomeContentComponent } from './home/home-content/home-content.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AboutComponent,
    AbtSec01Component,
    HomeComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    ErrorComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    MainComponent,
    HomeContentComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    routes
  ],
  providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
  })
  export class AppModule { }
```

Then again thank you all for reminding me to include the routing module apologies again.

Comment: Can you please add your router configuration from your module?

Comment: @user184994 thanks for reminding me, I just add the app-routing.module.ts and app.module.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this
in your component

```
this.router.navigate(['home']);
```

or

```
<a routerLink="/home" >HOME</a>
```

in your routing module

```
{ path: 'home', redirectTo: 'YOUR-MAIN.component', pathMatch: 'full' },
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two option for navigatoin

from HTML

```
<a routerLink="/works" >Works</a>
```

of from ts

```
this.router.navigate(['works']);
```

i think you are useing it worng and i guss that in youre routing page you have

```
{ path: '**', component: HomeComponent }
```

and its redirecting you to home page. try to use it as i suggest and if its not working please update you question  and add the routing file

Comment: thanks for reminding me, I just add the app-routing.module.ts and app.module.ts

Answer (score 0):

In html :

```
<a routerLink="/works" >Works</a>
```

In Typescript :

```
this.router.navigate(['works']);
```

Or routing :

```
{ path: 'home', redirectTo: 'YOUR-MAIN.component', pathMatch: 'full' }
```